# How do you set the background black in swing with a rectangle

Tags: java, swing, canvas, draw, java-2d

I am trying to create a simple JFrame with a rectangle drawn on it. The rectangle is acting as a background in this case. I have set up a render, tick, run, stop, and start method to keep track of my program.

```
package ghp.tilegame.main;

// Import java. 

import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Game extends Canvas implements Runnable
{

// Create variables

public static final int WIDTH = 360, HEIGHT = 240, SCALE = 2;
public static boolean running = false;
public Thread gameThread;


// Start method

public synchronized void start()
{

    // In running is already true get out of the method

    if(running)return;

    // Set running = true

    running = true;

    // Make a thread and start it

    gameThread = new Thread(this);
    gameThread.start();
}

// Stop method

public synchronized void stop()
{

    // If game is already stopped get out of the method

    if(!running)return;

    // Set running = false

    running = false;

    // Join the gameThread

    try 
    {
        gameThread.join();
    }
    catch(InterruptedException e)
    {

        // Print the error

        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}


// Run method

public void run()
{
    // Create variables

    long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
    final double amountOfTicks = 60D;
    double ns = 1000000000 / amountOfTicks;
    double delta = 0;

    // While running = true

    while(running)
    {

        // Create variables

        long now = System.nanoTime();
        delta += (now - lastTime) / ns;
        lastTime = now;

        // Tick Timer

        if(delta >= 1)
        {
            tick();
            delta--;
        }

        // Call the tick and render methods

        render();
    }

    // Exit

    stop();

}





// Tick method

public void tick()
{

}

// Render method

public void render()
{
    BufferStrategy bs = this.getBufferStrategy();
    if(bs == null)
    {
        createBufferStrategy(3);
        return;
    }

    Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();

    g.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH * SCALE, HEIGHT * SCALE);

    g.dispose();
    bs.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{

    // Create instance

    Game game = new Game();

    // Set the sizes of the Canvas

    game.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH * SCALE, HEIGHT * SCALE));
    game.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(WIDTH * SCALE, HEIGHT * SCALE));
    game.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(WIDTH * SCALE, HEIGHT * SCALE));

    // Set up JFrame

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Tile RPG");
    frame.setSize(WIDTH * SCALE, HEIGHT * SCALE);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.add(game);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

When I run the program the screen shows up as a gray screen! I want it to be black. What am i doing wrong with the render method?

Comment: Why not just use the `setBackground()` method on the `JFrame's` content pane itself instead of constructing your own?

Comment: Because it's not about setting the background color, it's about being able to draw a rectangle on my Frame

Comment: I figured out my problem! I had to add game.start(); into the main class

Comment: IMHO, you are doing a terrible mistake, in this program of your's. You mixing `AWT (Heavyweight)` components with `Swing (Lightweight)` components, which is a really bad practice. Instead of using `Canvas` use `JPanel/JComponent` and draw inside it's `paintComponent` method. For more information: [Painting Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)

Comment: I am using this program to try to create a simple rpg. Considering that should I still use paintComponent and JPanel.